# How do you change to master mode?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I want to change my game to master mode, (BOTW DLC) without deleting my save file. The reason is that I want to change my white lynels to silver and silver to gold. I'm pretty sure you can do that. I'm not sure how, though.

Comment: Have you already purchased and downloaded the Master Trials (DLC pack 1)?

Comment: Yes my dad plays BOTW too so I used his switch to do the DLC things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To unlock Master Mode, you must purchase and download The Master Trials (DLC pack 1). After doing so, you should see an option to start "Master Mode" on the main menu.

Selecting Master Mode for the first time will start you with a new game. **It is not possible to switch your current save to master mode.** However, starting in Master Mode will not clear your current save. You will be able to toggle between your normal mode save and your master mode save on the main menu.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just scared of the Lynel at the beginning. I watched a couple of youtubers fail to get past that Lynel. In my current save file, I have every divine beast except for Urbosa, so I can easily defeat Lynels.

Comment: @Struck Master Mode is a *whole* lot of fun. But you'll definitely find yourself running from enemy encounters for the first 10-15hrs (just to conserve weapons if nothing else) that you would've fought easily in normal mode. Good luck!

Comment: I know, but I hate the regeneration thing. If the regen goes slower, then it would be ok. Also, the Beginning Lynel thing is scary

Comment: @StruckZeus that early game lynel is easily avoidable though.  I enjoy masters mode a lot, the balloon platforms adds a great way to power up early on as they usually contain good weapons.

Comment: I tried to avoid it but I got caught anyways the notice range of a lynel is HUGE!

Comment: I did master mode, and it was pretty easy if you know where to go and beat the game before.